# Netlify redirects not working with Nuxt 3 static site

Tags: redirect, nuxt.js, netlify

I have generated and deployed a static site using **Nuxt 3** on **Netlify**. To, keep some old routes active, I have added some redirect rules in `netlify.toml` file, like this:

```ini
[[redirects]]
  from = "/tags/"
  to = "/posts/topics/"
  status = 301
```

and the site generation command was `nuxt generate` with `ssr: true` in `nuxt.config.ts` file. The redirect rules are successfully discovered by Netlify as shown in their **Production Deploy** log.

The redirects are not working in production. For example, `site.com/tags/` should redirect to `site.com/posts/topics/` but I guess Nuxt is catching the route and showing 404 page instead of redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found and solved the issue and I think it should be shared as an answer.

In the **Netlify** configuration file `netlify.toml`, there was a redirect rule for `404` status code before other redirect rules like this:

```ini
[[redirects]]
 from = "/*"
 status = 404
 to = "/404.html"

[[redirects]]
 from = "/other"
 to = "/new/other"
```

Removing the rule for `404` and placing it at the end of all redirect rules solved the problem. Apparently, the issue was not with Nuxt.js but about the ordering of redirect rules in Netlify.

New redirect rule:

```ini
[[redirects]]
 from = "/other"
 to = "/new/other"

[[redirects]]
 from = "/*"
 status = 404
 to = "/404.html
```